# Two expressions with similar arrangement of coefficients, does it imply that the variables are same?

Tags: polynomials

If $a|x|^2 + b|x| + c = a|y|^2 + b|y| +c$, then is it always $|x|=|y|$ ?

Or similarly,

if  $a|x|^n + b|x|^{n-1} + c|x|^{n-2} = a|y|^n + b|y|^{n-1} + c|y|^{n-2}$, then is it $|x| = |y|$ ?

More generally, does it happen that,

when,
$a|x| + b|y| + c|z|  =  a|m| + a|n| + c|p|$

[where, a,b,c are constants. Others are variables]

then,  $|x|=|m|$ , $|y| = |n|$ and $|z| = |p|$ ?

---

Comment: A clear insight can be obtained by graphing the function $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$.  Does $f(x_1)$ ever equal $f(x_2)$ for different arguments $x_1\neq x_2$?  If this happens then the equality $x=y$ will not *always* be true.  However if $x,y$ are real numbers and the function $f(x)$ is strictly monotone, then it will be true.  That is, the continuous real functions that are injective (one-one) are precisely the strictly monotone continuous functions.

Comment: You have made a substantial edit to the Question, although it does not affect the ultimate point that knowing $f(|x|) = f(|y|)$, even in the special cases you set up, does not generally imply $|x|=|y|$.  I leave it as an exercise for you to modify the analysis @HenningMakholm gave in his Answer to tackle injectivity on $[0,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

In other words, you're asking whether the functions
$$ x \mapsto ax^2+bx+c \\
(x,y,z) \mapsto ax+by+cz $$
are [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function). No, they are not, in general.

$ax^2+bx+c$ *can* be injective, namely if (but only if) $a=0$ and $b\ne 0$.

$ax+by+cz$ is never injective no matter what $a$, $b$, and $c$ are.

Answer (score 1):

No
At first case, see $a=0$, $b=0$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: it follows that $$a(x^n-y^n)+b(x^{n-1}-y^{n-1})+c(x^{n-2}-y^{n-2})=0$$

Comment: you must factor the expression in the brackets

Comment: I suggest you go into some detail about the factoring and resulting conclusions if you wish your "answer" to be helpful to future Readers.

Comment: we consider the case $$n=3$$ then we have $$(x-y)(a(x^2+y^2+xy)+b(x+y)+c)=0$$

Comment: ok but in my comment you will find a hint to solve the problem

Answer (score -1):

In the first case, the answer is clear: yes. But not only. You have in general two solutions. Let be:
$$s=x-y$$
$$t=x+y$$
$$a(x^2-y^2)+b(x-y)=0$$
$$a(x-y)(x+y)+b(x-y)=0$$

Then $ast+bs=0$, $s(at+b)=0$ That bring us two solutions: $s=0$, $x=y$ and $t=\frac{-b}{a}$, $y=\frac{-b}{a}-x$